# Not getting return value from Service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return the output of my service below to controller's calling  variable "response". The service does gets called and it also have an output however it never gets back to my calling again. What Am i doing wrong here?

```
this.AssociatetoJob1 = function (application) {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
        }
    };
    return $http.post('/api/Application/AddApplication', 
        JSON.stringify(application), config).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });     
}
```

And below is the line from my calling Controller:

```
var response = CandidateService.AssociatetoJob1(appInfom);
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but I'm really unsure what "it never gets back to my calling again" means or how you are determining that happens (since there's no sign of the `response` variable ever being inspected).

Comment: sorry not clear what you mean?

Comment: That makes two of us.

Comment: you should do like blow :

CandidateService.AssociatetoJob1(appInfom).then(function(response){
   response = response.data
})

Comment: Could you try to add an error callback handler and log it? maybe you are getting a 404 or something other http error that you are not catching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.AssociatetoJob1 = function (application) {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }
    return $http.post('/api/Application/AddApplication', JSON.stringify(application), config).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });

}
```

above code does return you Promise object. So as to utilize this you need to do something like below in controller:

```
  var responseData ; 
  CandidateService.AssociatetoJob1(appInfom).then(function(res‌​ponse){ 
     responseData  = response.data ;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `contentType` is wrong.Change it like this `Content-Type`

**JS**:

```
    this.AssociatetoJob1 = function (application) {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }
    return $http.post('/api/Application/AddApplication', JSON.stringify(application), config).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });

}
```

**HTML**

```
var response = CandidateService.AssociatetoJob1(appInfom);
```

You can get the details returned by your API call by using .then on the promise which was resolved.

```
response.then(function(result){
  console.log(result.data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "this.AssociatetoJob1" function, you called the service like

```
return $http.post('/api/Application/AddApplication', JSON.stringify(application), config).then(function (result) {
    return result.data;
});
```

In this you have used a callback function while calling the service, Instead of this, call the service like

```
return $http.post('/api/Application/AddApplication', JSON.stringify(application), config);
```

that means just remove the .then() callback from your service call and call "this.AssociatetoJob1" method like

```
this.AssociatetoJob1(application).then(function(response){console.log(response.Data)});
```

Hope It helped you...